# Xamarin.Forms - TypeLoadException Failure has occurred while loading a type

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using portable Xamarin forms - CrossPlatform.
In xamarin form there are two projects Android and IOS

Below code is working perfectly when I run in android APP.
But same code is not working in IOS.

It is giving error "Failure has occurred while loading a type" on line "var response = await client.Execute(request);"

Below is my code

```cs
public async Task<ResponseGeneralObject<TokenModel>> LoginUser(LoginModel loginModel)
{
    ResponseGeneralObject<TokenModel> result = new ResponseGeneralObject<TokenModel>();
    try
    {
        var restUrl = App.URLServicePath + "token";
        var client = new RestClient(restUrl);
        TokenModel model = new TokenModel();

        var request = new RestRequest("", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
        request.AddParameter("username", loginModel.UserName);
        request.AddParameter("password", loginModel.Password);

        var response = await client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;

        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            result.data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenModel>(content);
            // model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<TokenModel>(response.Result.Content);
            result.iserror = false;
        }
        else
        {
            result.iserror = true;
            result.message = "Internal error!";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.iserror = true;
        result.message = ex.Message;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a 3rd party library for the `RestClient`? If so make sure the version that is referenced matches across your iOS, Android, and PCL projects. I have seen `TypeLoadExceptions` when there is a package mismatch between the PCL and platform projects.